# Github Actions fails to deploy at to Azure due to yarn issues despite local development works fine

Tags: vuejs3, hadoop-yarn, nuxt3, tailwind-ui

When I deploy my application to github actions it fails with the following error:

```
yarn install v1.22.15
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning Pattern ["strip-ansi@^6.0.1"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-strip-ansi-cjs-6.0.1-9e26c63d30f53443e9489495b2105d37b67a85d9-integrity/node_modules/strip-ansi-cjs" as pattern ["strip-ansi-cjs@npm:strip-ansi@^6.0.1"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
warning Pattern ["string-width@^4.1.0"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-string-width-cjs-4.2.3-269c7117d27b05ad2e536830a8ec895ef9c6d010-integrity/node_modules/string-width-cjs" as pattern ["string-width-cjs@npm:string-width@^4.2.0"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
warning Pattern ["strip-ansi@^6.0.0"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-strip-ansi-cjs-6.0.1-9e26c63d30f53443e9489495b2105d37b67a85d9-integrity/node_modules/strip-ansi-cjs" as pattern ["strip-ansi-cjs@npm:strip-ansi@^6.0.1"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
warning Pattern ["string-width@^4.2.3"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-string-width-cjs-4.2.3-269c7117d27b05ad2e536830a8ec895ef9c6d010-integrity/node_modules/string-width-cjs" as pattern ["string-width-cjs@npm:string-width@^4.2.0"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
warning Pattern ["string-width@^4.2.0"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-string-width-cjs-4.2.3-269c7117d27b05ad2e536830a8ec895ef9c6d010-integrity/node_modules/string-width-cjs" as pattern ["string-width-cjs@npm:string-width@^4.2.0"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
warning Pattern ["wrap-ansi@^7.0.0"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-wrap-ansi-cjs-7.0.0-67e145cff510a6a6984bdf1152911d69d2eb9e43-integrity/node_modules/wrap-ansi-cjs" as pattern ["wrap-ansi-cjs@npm:wrap-ansi@^7.0.0"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
warning Pattern ["string-width@^1.0.2 || 2 || 3 || 4"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-string-width-cjs-4.2.3-269c7117d27b05ad2e536830a8ec895ef9c6d010-integrity/node_modules/string-width-cjs" as pattern ["string-width-cjs@npm:string-width@^4.2.0"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
error globby@14.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=18". Got "16.20.2"
error Found incompatible module.
```

I am not sure why this would fail here but not locally? I also would note that checked my node version with node -v and its v21.6.1 so not sure why it says it Got 16.20.2. Also, this warning error is new as well despite I have not touched anything with that module or even know what it is to be honest. I am using a vue3/nuxt3/tailwindui setup and very basic installation.

Update 1/29/24
After using Yoduh's suggestion of setting the node version in the yaml file I get the next error:

```
    [error] require() of ES Module /github/workspace/node_modules/string-width/index.js from /github/workspace/node_modules/wide-align/align.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /github/workspace/node_modules/wide-align/align.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
  Instead change the require of index.js in node_modules/wide-align/align.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/wide-align/align.js:2:19) 

[error] require() of ES Module /github/workspace/node_modules/string-width/index.js from /github/workspace/node_modules/wide-align/align.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /github/workspace/node_modules/wide-align/align.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

This relates to some of the warnings it looks like. I am still unsure why this is working locally but not on azure deployment.

Comment: When you ran `node -v` was it just on your local machine?  The error comes from the azure environment where the app is being deployed to.  I believe you should be able to set the node version in your Github Actions workflow script like in the example seen [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-to-your-cloud-provider/deploying-to-azure/deploying-nodejs-to-azure-app-service#creating-the-workflow) in the documentation.

Comment: That did the trick but led to an error that has me scratching my head: [error] require() of ES Module /github/workspace/node_modules/string-width/index.js from /github/workspace/node_modules/wide-align/align.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /github/workspace/node_modules/wide-align/align.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
  Instead change the require of index.js in node_modules/wide-align/align.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/wide-align/align.js:2:19)

Comment: Same issue is reported on the [nuxt github](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/21231) and there are a few solutions posted.  maybe one of them can help.